# Is there a specific screen resolution that should be used when Mapping objects?

Tags: automated-testing, testcomplete

I'm using [TestComplete](http://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/) 10.50 demo version. My screen resolution is 1366 X 768, and when I try to map objects, the highlighted objects are a little bit indented to the left from the original object.

For example if you try to add NameMapping for [www.gmail.com](https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html) "SignIn" Link, the object highlighted is at the left of the the original SignIn Link so when running `Aliases.IE_Browser.Link_GmailSignIn.Click()`, the action goes to a wrong space.

Can any one please help ?

[image]

Comment: I can't help but feel that multiple resolutions is part of why we automate tests, so we can run the same series of tests on multiple resolutions to make sure our system is still usable. So my gut instinct tells me no, there isn't.

Comment: @Ragda Are you trying to specify button positions using (x,y) coordinates?

Comment: No , I'm not using (x,y) coordinates , I'm just using Click().
But it seems that this problem happens only with IE , because I tried it latter and it ran successfully many times .

Comment: What version of IE are you testing with? I couldn't find this signin link on the main page of www.gmail.com, but it looks similar on https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html for people who might want to reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing isn't usually related to screen resolution but instead to browser zoom level. Is IE set to zoom at all? Sometimes this can accidentally occur due to accidental activation of keyboard shortcuts, so do actually check.

Comment: I think you are right , I don't remember what was the situation when I wrote this post , but I maybe I did some zoom changes by mistake , because latter everything was working fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its one of the following issues:

- The element was found on the location it clicks, but the page was not done rendering yet and the element is pushed into another location before the actual click. Since older version of IE could be somewhat slower this used to happen a lot to me. Make sure you wait until the page is done rendering or add a small timeout before the click to verify this is the case.
- The element is actually bigger, for example its a div with a much larger size. You might be trying to click the center of the div instead of link text. Make sure you are really clicking the link text and not the center of another element.